# Hacer diagonales en css

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando recrear una imagen en CSS pero no me sale la "diagonal" como se muestra en la imagen.

Hasta ahora solo pude sobreponer los dos colores creando 3 div's, el contenedor, el azul y el dorado.

Comment: 1. No se ve la imagen, 2. agrega un ejemplo de tu codigo 3. No agregues tu codigo en imagenes

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) , y tambien [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    .button{
        background: linear- 
        gradient(140deg, #00C9FF 35%, 
        transparent 35%);
    }
    <button class="button">some long text</button>
```

Comment: Esta seccion es solo para respuestas, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y eliminar esta NO respuesta

Comment: @David081 también creí que era el mismo usuario respondiéndose, pero son dos usuarios diferentes jaja

Comment: Ídem @EvilFearzZ, y tuve que borrar mi comentario. Conviene reportar la pregunta, pareciera ser [sock puppeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet_account).